# How to execute moving average method in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

My application scenario of using Apache IoTDB involves keeping track of price trends for specific securities. Therefore, if the database can generate moving average method to capture the average change in a data series over time, that will be very helpful for me. I wonder if IoTDB can execute moving average method and how exactly can I do that?

Realy no idea. Someone help please.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `MVAVG` UDF function included in Apache IoTDB.

To use this UDF, you also need to set parameter `window` to be the length of moving window you want, and the default value is 10.

An example command may be:

> select mvavg(s1, "window"="3") from root.test